# How to solve 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, c#-4.0

Following code gives me below error -

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Func)' has some
>   invalid arguments

```
public Task<string[]> SayHelloAsync()
{
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(GreetUser());
    Task<string> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(GreetCustomer());
    Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
private string GreetUser()
{
    return "Hello";
}

private string GreetCustomer()
{
    return "Namaste";
}
```

Whats wrong with this.
I am using ASP.Net MVC

Comment: Add the error to your question.

Comment: What's is the error? please don't screenshot code - people with the same problem won't be able to see this in search results.

Comment: @Cacho

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<string>(System.Func<string>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Foobar 
Sure..

and this is the error
Error:1
**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<string>(System.Func<string>)' has some invalid arguments **

Error2:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func<string>'

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GreetUser());`

Comment: I changed the title and format of the question, so that it is more contextual. Please avoid having generic question title and body, so that it will be misinterpreted. Finally I m glad I was able to solve to your question. I posted the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Func)'
>   has some invalid arguments

You should state a new task in following way -

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GreetUser());
```

overall the method should be like -

```
public Task<string[]> SayHelloAsync()
{
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GreetUser());
    Task<string> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GreetCustomer());
    return Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
private string GreetUser()
{
    return "Hi";
}

private string GreetCustomer()
{
    return "Hi";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on ramiramilu's answers, if your `DoWork` method is parameterless you can just pass it and it will also work (note that you just need to pass the method, not CALL the method).

```
    void StartWork()
    {
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(DoWork);  //note, you're using "DoWork", not "DoWork()"!!!
    }

    string DoWork()
    {
        //do stuff
        return "stuff";
    }
```

Using the lambda expressions is only needed when your `DoWork` methods require input parameters which you want to pass from the calling method. In this case you NEED to use the lambda expression.

```
    void StartWork()
    {
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => DoWork("my param"));
    }

    string DoWork(string myParams)
    {
        //do stuff
        return myParams;
    }
```

Otherwise, you can just pass the name of the method and call it a day.